# Analytics Custom Report of pages with most goals recorded has no data

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

I'm trying to make a list of the "most favorited" pages, but no data is coming out in the finished report.

When the user clicks a favorite button, it triggers the built-in "Like" goal for that page. This works fine, and the data I want is visible in the Fact_Conversions table in the Sitecore_Analytics database.

So the MongoDB recording is working, and aggregation is working.
I think this should only need a custom segment/filter combo.

There's a filter with the rule:
"where the Like goal was triggered during the current visit, add visit to segment"

That filter is associated with a custom segment in
Pages/By Page

I've added that segment to a bar chart item in the custom report layout using a parameters item, and with Metric: Conversions

There are no error messages, and the report just says "no data to display"

I've already rebuilt the reporting database as well.

I made a custom bar chart that simply displays the built-in segment "all visits by page" with Metric: Conversions, and that works fine, it just doesn't separate out which goal is which.

What might I have done wrong setting up my custom segment? Or have I completely misunderstood how the custom reports work?

Comment: Troubleshooting question number one with Sitecore is almost always "did you publish," but when working with segments the question is "did you deploy?" You provided a pretty detailed description (omitting but implying the use of Dimensions), but you never mentioned actually clicking "Deploy" on your segment. Give that a shot, allow the configured amount of time to deploy (30 minutes, by default) to elapse (I would wait an extra few just to be safe), and then either rebuild the reporting database again or test it by satisfying the goal and waiting for the data to show up in the reporting DB.

Comment: I tried deploying the segments and rebuilt the database but don't see any changes. I'm just using the built in Pages dimension, there's no changes there. Thank you for the advice though.

Comment: No problem. In that case, I recommend you raise the question to Sitecore Support and ask them to take a look at it. They should be able to help you resolve the issue. Once you have a solution, you should add it as an answer to this question with as much detail as possible. It's a good opportunity to help others and earn some SSE points as a new member ;) Good luck!

Comment: @rallan did you ever find a solution for this?
I'm also looking for a report on Goals per Pages.

Comment: Unfortunately no, we never did figure it out. Sorry